# how to tokenize each sentence from the paragraph in java

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

I am trying to **tokenize each sentence from pragraph** using split() function if it have "."(dot), so wherever "."(dot) is there it will split the sentences, but i am **facing some issue** like, when i have a sentence like "**'A clam for supper? a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs. Hussey?" says I**., it is considering as two sentence like 1) **'A clam for supper? a cold clam; is THAT what you mean, Mrs.** 2) **Hussey?" says I**. It should be only single sentence, how to overcome this problem. plz help me. In similar way words like **"Mr. , Dr. , Jr. ,Sr. ,"** etc. I need it to be a single sentence only, how can i tokenize it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a full definition of a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion to match all the dots or `?` or `!` symbols which is not preceded by `Mrs` or `Mr` or `Dr` or `Sr` or `Jr` and not followed by a non-space character.

```
String parts[] = s.split("(?<![DSJ]r|Mrs?)[.?!](?!\\S)");
```

Comment: @ Avinash Raj .....i have my split function like                                                                                                                // split on a ".", a "!", a "?" followed by a space or EOL
         return input.split("(\\.|!|\\?)+(\\s|\\z)");
how to add along with it the one which u mentioned. Please help

Comment: ....in similar way i am facing same issue when sentence comes along with month and days like Today, Jan.17-is the good day, Its splitting Jan and 17 as two different sentence. how to overcome it

Comment: avinash raj...can u explain that line..like what all it indicates